# Follow object in editor (3d view)

Tags: 3d-view

I'm animating a character that is moving around a scene.

To have a nice view of some of the bones I want to animate, I move to the specific frame, then press `.` in the NUMPAD, but is pretty annoying to do this all the time.

Is there a way to make the 3d View in Blender follow some objects? (I'm not talking about the camera for rendering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the view tab you can choose "lock to object". If you want, you can also check "lock camera to view".

[image]

example (as you can see, this is not the camera, because the camera will come in the view at the end)

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!!

Comment: you are welcome. If it helped you, please check the checkmark left of my answer. Thanks.